# Timelines stacked using pgfplots

Tags: pgfplots

I am trying to create a plot with execution times looking a bit like this (I want an axis with time on the bottom):

```
fooer   XXXXX 
foo2bar      XXXXX
        |    |     |
```

Where (in this example) fooer starts at 0 and goes to 600 and foo2bar starts at 600 and goes to 1020. In the genreal case the numbers can be much bigger so large numebrs needs to be supported. I previously attempted to do this with the pgfgant package [Gantt chart with milliseconds as input](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/438531/gantt-chart-with-milliseconds-as-input) but I am now thinking perhaps pgfplots is a better approach. I found some examples on the Internet and thinking that this is pretty much a bar plot I set of:

```
\documentclass[11pt,twoside,openright]{memoir}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}


    \begin{document}
        \begin{tikzpicture}
      \begin{axis}[
        xbar,
        y axis line style = { opacity = 0 },
        axis x line       = none,
        tickwidth         = 0pt,
        symbolic y coords = {fooer, foo2bar},
        nodes near coords,
      ]
      \addplot coordinates { (600,fooer) (1020,foo2bar+600) };
      \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{document}
```

[image]

As you can see I am not even near... My example has many lines (I was going for two), overlapping plotting (no idea why), and a blue color that I have no idea where it came from but since I want to define colors myself I am least glad there is some color. Clearly I need help, this wasn't as easy as I was hoping... :/

---

EDIT: With the help of tex.stackexchange.com/questions/401935 I came a bit further:

```
\documentclass[11pt,twoside,openright]{memoir}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\definecolor{color1}{RGB}{146,200,180}
\definecolor{color2}{RGB}{124,206,89}

\pgfplotstableread[col sep=comma]{
y,start,end,color
0,0,600,color1
1,600,1020,color2
}\loadedtable


\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
  xbar,
  y axis line style = { opacity = 0 },
  axis x line       = none,
  tickwidth         = 0pt,
  xbar stacked, % means that the bars from the different \addplots are stacked one after the other
  y dir=reverse % means the y-axis increases downward
]
% make an invisible bar from zero to the start-value
\addplot [draw=none, forget plot] table [col sep=comma,x=start, y=y]{\loadedtable};
% then add the actual bar, stacked after the invisible one
% for pgfplots the x-value is the length of the bar, so
% we calculate end minus start 
\addplot  +[fill=black,draw=none] table [x expr=\thisrow{end}-\thisrow{start}, y=y] {\loadedtable};

% fill background
\fill [\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/color}] (\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/xmin}, \pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/ymax}) rectangle
                 (\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/xmax}, 6.5);
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

I get three lines though, seems the one that is supposed to be transparent is not transparent. My colors does not seems to work at all and then there is the issue of all the space between them.

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/401935/ might be of interest. The color is a `pgfplots` default. Your example throws an error, because you use `foobar2+600` as the y-coordinate which doesn't make sense in the first place, and the error is because the symbolic coordinate you defined is `foobar2`, not `foobar2+600`.

Comment: Oh is that the y coordinate. I wanted to change the starting position, the x coordinate...

Comment: Yes, it's always `coordinates { (x1, y1) (x2, y2) <etc.>}`. Bars in `xbar`/`ybar` always start at zero, so to have a bar start at some other value you need to use `xbar stacked`, and plot an invisible bar first. A better example than the previous link I mentioned is https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/147012/x-bar-plot-with-intervall-a-b-rather-than-0-a/147024#147024

Comment: Anotehr stab at color `\addplot+[\thisrow{color}] table [x expr=\thisrow{start}-\thisrow{end}, y=Name]{\loadedtable};
` but that doesn't work either. Is it not possible to change the colors... :(

Answer (score 1):

If you are interested in a solution, I came up with this:

```
\documentclass[11pt,twoside,openright]{memoir}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\definecolor{color1}{RGB}{146,200,180}
\definecolor{color2}{RGB}{124,206,89}

\pgfplotstableread[col sep=comma]{
start,end,Name,color
0,600,fooer,color1
600,1020,foo2bar,color2
}\loadedtable


\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    xbar, xmin=0,
    y axis line style = { opacity = 0 },
    tickwidth         = 0pt,
    width=12cm, height=3.5cm, enlarge y limits=0.5,
    symbolic y coords={fooer,foo2bar},
    ytick=data, xbar stacked,
    bar shift=0pt,
    y dir=reverse,
    xtick={1, 500, 1000},
    xticklabels={1 ms, 500 ms, 1 s}
]

\addplot [draw=none, forget plot] table [x=end, y=Name]{\loadedtable};
\addplot table [x expr=\thisrow{start}-\thisrow{end}, y=Name]{\loadedtable};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]